# Swashbuckle serialization of multipart form data

Tags: c#, .net, multipartform-data, swashbuckle

I have two parameters in the controller method, one is a form file and the second one is a DTO object which is a part of the form data as well:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestMethod(
        [Required]IFormFile file,
        [FromForm][ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ModelBinder))]Options? options = null)
```

I want the "Options" to be serialized as a type into the Swagger specification. By default the Swashbuckle generates plain list of properties taken from both the "Options" type along with the "file" property. The type "Options" itself is ignored.

If the [FromForm] attribute is omitted, the "Options" serialized as a type, but in this case it becomes a query parameter, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a known bug [[FromForm] and lists are not serialized correctly](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1107). Try to downgrade your Swagger version to `v. 5.6.3`.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.